# Can Prisma Scalar list filter do LIKE %value%

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a filter array of words e.g. `["value1", "value2"]`

In my Prisma db I have a model which has a scalar column

```
model Keywords {
  ....
  words String[]
}
```

I want to perform a filtering where I pull all Keywords entities based the filter array input.

The filtering should match any Keywords objects where any element in the filter array is `like %word%`.

I know [from the API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#scalar-list-filters)  you can do `hasSome` filter e.g.

```
{
  words: {
    hasSome: filterArray,
  },
},
```

However this is doing a full match on each compared word to filter element and not `like %word%` if that makes sense?

Is there a way to achieve what I want with these filters?

Example:

```
Keywords has entity
words=["value1", "value3"]
filters=["value11", "value22"]
```

Since `value1` is like `value11` this record should be matched.